# https.request não envia body se for o method DELETE

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou a fazer um pedido para fazer um `DELETE`, e tenho um problema, ao fazer o pedido, o `bodyParams` não é passado.

Alguém já teve algum problema similar? Do outro lado estou a usar o express `req.body` e `req.query`.

De seguida está parte da função. O estranho é que ao fazer um `POST`, este funciona:

```
function request({
  options,
  method,
  resource,
  queryParams,
  bodyParams,
}) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const stringifyedQueryParams = strigifyQueryParams(queryParams);

    const optionsRequest = {
      ...options,
      method,
      path: `${resource}${stringifyedQueryParams}`,
    };

    const req = https.request(optionsRequest, (res) => {
      res.setEncoding(configs.ENCODING);
      res.on(events.DATA, data => resolve({
        body: data,
        statusCode: res.statusCode,
      }));
    });

    req.on(events.ERROR, error => reject(error) );
    req.write(JSON.strigify(bodyParams));
    req.end();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pela especificação, a requisição `DELETE`[não possui semântica definida para o `body`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/DELETE). Provavelmente por isso ele está sendo ignorado.

Comment: Certo, mas por exemplo se utilizar o plugin request (https://github.com/request/request) consigo enviar o body no delete. Não é possível fazer isso de forma nativa no node js?